# Setting to zero in Xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a variable with multiple dimensions concentration[time,lon, lat], I have found spurios negative concentration values at different times and at different lon and lattitude. I would like to set everything below 0 to zero, using xarray.

Is there straight forward way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply numpy and scipy [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html), a.k.a. universal functions, which operate element-wise on a whole array, to an xarray object and the result will still be an xarray object. In this case:

```py
da = np.maximum(da, 0)
```

See the xarray docs on [computation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#basic-array-math) for more description.